# Compute φ = (p−1)(q−1); in java

Tags: java, algorithm, cryptography, rsa

I have 2 big integers and now i need to compute φ in java. Here my existing code, I'm having difficulties writing the actual formula to Compute φ = (p−1)(q−1); in java. Thanks

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.*;

public class RawRSA {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

BigInteger p = BigInteger.probablePrime(128, new Random());
BigInteger q = BigInteger.probablePrime(128, new Random());
BigInteger n = p.multiply(q);
BigInteger phi = // this is where the formula needs to go;

System.out.println(p);
System.out.println(q);
System.out.println(n);

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Build it up in steps.

p-1 is `p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)`. q-1 is `q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)`. You already know how to multiply:

```
BigInteger phi = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
```